# ZendeskSDKMessaging iOS integration problem

Tags: ios, swift, zendesk, zendesk-sdk

I'm trying to integrate Zendesk messaging in my iOS app with this [doc](https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/zendesk-web-widget-sdks/sdks/ios/getting_started/)
and I can't init Zendesk properly.

If I add only ZendeskSDKMesaging framework as it written in the documentation, I receive the error "Cannot find 'Zendesk' in scope". So I'm adding ZendeskCoreSDK but now it has no initialisation method as in the instruction Zendesk.initialize(withChannelKey..., it only shows the one for SupportSDK with appID and clientID, not with channel key. Did anyone faces with the same problem?

Comment: "Add the SDK dependencies" Which solution did you use? Manually? if yes, it seems you need to add a few and not only one, as there are dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I know Zendesk may seem very complex when you first tackle it. The doc that you mentioned here is outdated I believe, Zendesk no longer initializes like that and that may be the issue your having.

Take a look at these docs instead:

1. [Add the Unified SDK to your Project](https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/classic-web-widget-sdks/unified-sdk/ios/sdk_add/)
2. [Initializing the Unified SDK dependencies](https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/classic-web-widget-sdks/unified-sdk/ios/sdk_initialize/)

In this case, if you have all of the correct imports you should have something like this:

```swift
// Where you initialize the Zendesk
// In the beginning of the file
import ZendeskCoreSDK
import SupportProvidersSDK
import AnswerBotProvidersSDK

func zendeskInitializer() {
   Zendesk.initialize(appId: YOUR_APP_ID, clientId:   YOUR_CLIENT_ID, zendeskUrl: YOUR_URL)
   Support.initialize(withZendesk: Zendesk.instance)
   AnswerBot.initialize(withZendesk: Zendesk.instance, support: Support.instance!)
}
```

I hope I was able to help. Have a great week.